# Problem when connect ProPIC2 and USB to Parallel port adapter

Tags: pic, driver, programmer, adapter

I have a ProPIC 2 programmer which needs parallel port (DB25) to work but I don't have in my notebook that port (SO: Windows 8), so I'm using a USB-Parallel adapter.

When I connect the device it installs the driver correctly but not recognize the programmer.
If I go to "Manage devices" my adapter is shown as an USB connection and not as parallel port.
Here appears a little message : "No printer connected".

Could you tell me if it's possible to connect the programmer with an adapter?
Thank you.

Comment: In general USB to parallel port adapters tend to only work with printers, so it seems that you're out of luck.

Comment: It's time to switch to a USB-based programmer. There are many on the market and most of them are quite reasonably priced.

Comment: Old programmers of various sorts (including PIC's) access the hardware of the printer port at the chip level and register level to bit bang custom protocols to the programmers. When you switch to USB these chips  and registers are no longer available. They may be simulated in the windows drivers but they are not replicated in the USB printer adaptors. As the Gents above have stated ... it's time to switch to a USB version.

Comment: This seems to be a better fit on the superuser StackExchange site as it's a PC hardware/driver problem.